# Attach shower to roman tub

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, bathtub, diy-vs-pro

I have a **Roman Tub** at my home and want to attach a **shower** to it. My plan was to find an adaptor that could attach to the roman tub faucet and connect with a shower diverter, attach and mount handheld shower to the wall. I haven't had any luck finding an adaptor at Home Depot or via research online.

It makes me think either this is impossible (which is hard to believe - there must be a hacky solution to it haha) OR I'm looking at this the wrong way. I'll be meeting w/plumbers next week.[image: Roman Tub]

[image: Roman Tub Faucet]
I've attached a few images too. What would the best option be?

Please advise!

Comment: probably have to remove the the faucet and attach a diverter there

Comment: I don't see any `screws` on the faucet or the water taps. Do you think it's behind the white circular box? I haven't tried removing it myself ... just a bit nervous and didn't want to mess anything up @Jasen

Comment: the might be a small hex socket screw at the back of the faucet. I wouldn't expect any access through the overflow. I'm not familiar with this model.

Comment: Will look into that. Also, I haven't been able to find deck mounted tub faucets w/diverters -- only found wall mounted tub faucets with diverters. Thoughts? @Jasen

Comment: I have put showers in but used 3 valve model installed in the wall on most 1 had a mid faucet and brought the valves up behind the faucet , I did not think it looked very practical but the owner loved it large 6’ jacuzzi tub (the valves in the entry side mid way).